# What problems can arise when mixing JPA with plain-JDBC dao implementations?

Tags: database, jpa, jdbc, orm

We have two teams who want to access the same database using different technologies. One uses JPA (Hibernate, to be specific). The other uses plain JDBC.

I've been asked to compile a list of concerns assuming that each team uses the default configuration and/or "best practices" of each technology.

This is a new database, so imagine that the schema is being designed solely by the JPA team, or solely by the JDBC team, and then they both go about trying to access it.

Can you please share your experiences?

**UPDATE**: I'm not asking for opinions here. I don't care whether JPA or JDBC is "better". I am asking for an objective list of interoperability concerns when mixing the two technologies.

---

Here is an example of what I'm looking for:

Scenario: A user reads a row, modifies it in memory, and saves it back to the database.

- If JPA uses optimistic locking by adding a `version` column to each table.
- When the transaction is committed, JPA checks if the version changed between the time that the row was read and the time it was updated. If the version changed, it throws an exception. If not, it allows the commit to continue.
- If the JDBC implementation uses table locks (a.k.a. pessimistic locking), they use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` to prevent concurrent updates.
- Imagine what happens if the JDBC implementation is not aware of the JPA convention and does not update `version` on commit:

  1. JPA reads a row using `SELECT` and sees `version` equal to 1.
  2. JDBC reads a row using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.
  3. JDBC updates the row (committing its transaction) without incrementing `version`.
  4. JPA tries updating the row. The commit goes through because `version` is still equal to 1.
  5. JPA (step 4) just clobbered the update of JDBC (step 3).

Lesson learned: The JDBC implementation needs to know to update the `version` column.

Comment: I'd recommend putting a REST service in front of that database.  Neither team should be accessing it directly.  Write the service in one technology and let them access it in a consistent way.

Comment: @duffymo I made the same recommendation but there is strong pressure against it "for performance reasons". The more ammunition I get as a result of this question, the higher the probability that your suggestion will happen.

Comment: Why not allow direct reads against the shared database, but both applications agree that updates must be funneled through either a REST API or a message broker for consistent manipulation of data?

Comment: Let me predict the future: Neither team will back down.  You won't persuade anybody.  They'll both do it their own way.  The app will have a lifetime of problems, if it ever sees production.  You have my sympathy.

Comment: If it's JPA, both teams need to be using a common object model.  It's hard enough to design one application that way; impossible with two.  How do you plan to handle the evolution of the object model?  That would be a JPA killer for me.

Comment: @duffymo I think it doesn't matter JPA or not.  Two applications that want to share a domain model should adhere to the same rules.  You can accomplish that through different tech, but both teams have to be extremely judicious about their code when manipulating data.

Comment: @Naros Thank you. I'll suggest this but I will likely get a push-back because it requires using two different technologies (per application) to talk to the DB.

Comment: It does matter.  JPA requires an object model to work.  If the other team doesn't adhere to that model, or can't evolve with it, then JPA can't work.  You have to do lowest common denominator - JDBC - if they insist on sharing a data source.  Sounds like one app, two stubborn teams.

Comment: If it were me, I'd enforce the REST API that @duffymo suggested.  That's exactly how a lot of the big players in the industry handle this precise problem.  Amazon for example has multiple applications that read from shared databases, but they do so through a common API interface.  Whether that is accessed via REST or some other dependency, its a common technology.

Comment: If you can't win the argument, maybe Werner Vogel and Amazon can: https://apievangelist.com/2012/01/12/the-secret-to-amazons-success-internal-apis/

Comment: @duffymo as much as I appreciate the discussion, I would appreciate you posting some answers as well :) Your point about having to share an object model is a good one. Can you post that one and potentially add others?

Comment: Posting answers?  Are you objecting to my putting my thoughts in comments?  I thought the idea was to contribute.  What does it matter where I type them?

Comment: @duffymo it does. Comments are used to ask for clarifications of the question. Answers answer the question. You can't downvote a comment or provide code formatting, etc. They are intentionally crippled.

Comment: I didn't provide code.  Downvote?  Why?  Are you singling out anybody else for criticism besides me?  I see no answers, yet you address me.  I think the link to Werner Vogel, the CTO behind AWS, should be authoritative enough for you and your teams.

Comment: @duffymo I understand that's how you feel, and I appreciate the link, but you're not actually answering the technical question I asked :)

Comment: "JPA implementation favour optimistic" : nonsense. JPA implementations provide optimistic and pessimistic locking. They don't _favour_ either

Comment: @NeilStockton Look at the origins of JPA. Up until version 2.0 they did not support pessimistic locking at all. Much of the JPA documentation I have seen in the past was encouraging the use of optimistic-locking as a best practice.

Comment: Just because it did not have EXPLICIT pessimistic "support", it didn't exclude its usage in earlier versions, and if the user didn't put an `@Version` then they would have no optimistic locking either. No docs I've seen 'favour' anything, neither should they

Comment: @NeilStockton That is not my interpretation. Pre-JPA 2.0 there was, in fact, no way to use pessimistic locking. So in that sense, yes it did exclude its usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building my own list while waiting for other people to answer:

1. JPA uses optimistic-locking by default. This requires adding a version column and incrementing it each time the row is updated. JDBC would have to do the same.
2. Divergent DAO layers are more likely to end up with a divergent model. Meaning, any time the JPA mapping configuration is changed, the corresponding JDBC code might break silently.
3. If JPA uses cascading rules to propagate updates or deletes. JDBC would dhave to do the same.
4. If JPA `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)` is used, it creates and uses a sequence table (e.g. `hibernate_sequence`). JDBC would have to do the same.
5. JDBC would need to support JPA class inheritance tables.
6. If JPA drives schema evolution, the JDBC implementation would need to add support for its conventions/features. On the other hand, if JDBC drives schema evolution then we would need to disable JPA features that impact the schema.
7. Can't use JPA 2nd-level cache if data is modified outside of JPA (courtesy of [crizzis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1092818/crizzis))

Comment: Dont't forget about not being able to use 2nd level cache in your JPA application on entities that might be modified outside of JPA